# Как сделать так, чтобы изображение подстраивалось под высоту

Tags: css

Есть вот такая страница:
[image]

При уменьшении ширины экрана изображение само подстраивает пропорции и уменьшается
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при уменьшении высоты изображение не подстраивается под экран. Как решить эту проблему?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
        html,body{
            height: 100%;
            width:100%;
        }
        .image{
            position: relative;
            left: 15%;
            top: 15%;
            height:70%;
            width:70%;
        }
        #img{
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            margin: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="image">
    <img id="img" src="http://magic-kniga.ru/files/item_main_images/23000.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

div {
  height: 70%;
  width: 70%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://magic-kniga.ru/files/item_main_images/23000.jpg" />
</div>
```